# Use the prime factorization of $\phi(321)$ to determine possible orders of units mod 321

Tags: number-theory, modules

Use the prime factorization of $\phi(321)$ to determine possible orders of units mod
321.  (Your list should have fewer than ten numbers in it).

My attempt:

$\phi(321)$ = $\phi(3)\phi(107)$ = $2(3)$ =$212$

Factors of $212 = 1,2,4,53,106,212$

Now check:

Is $2^1$ congruent to $1mod212$?

Is $2^2$ congruent to $1mod212$?

Is $2^4$ congruent to $1mod212$?

Is $2^{53}$ congruent to $1mod212$?

Is $2^{106}$ congruent to $1mod212$?

Is $2^{212}$ congruent to $1mod212$?

Am I on the right track? How should I procede if I am wrong?

Comment: Your list is fine. It may be all that is asked for. To me the wording suggest that. But perhaps you may be expected to find which  of these $6$ candidates is actually the order of some unit. Hint: $212$ is not.

Comment: Depending on the order in which things are done, you may not have the background for a full discussion. Do you know that the units modulo a prime are a cyclic group? Or in other words, that every prime has a primitive roots?

Comment: The question is phrased a bit oddly.  One generally uses the factorization of $\phi(321)$ into smaller values of $\phi(\cdot)$ to determine the possible orders of units.  The prime factorization isn't good enough because it loses information about which factors came from which $\phi$ term.  For instance $\phi(97)$ and $\phi(420)$ have the same **prime** factorization but the unit groups mod 97 and 420 are quite different.

Answer (score 1):

By Euler's theorem we have $x^{\varphi(321)}\equiv 1 \bmod 321$ for every unit $\bmod 321$.

This implies the order of every unit is a divisor of $\varphi(321)$.

As you noted $\varphi(321)=\varphi(3\times 107)=2\times 106=2^253^1$. Therefore the orders of units must be divisors of $\varphi(321)$, having the prime factorization we rapidly find there are only $6$ of them and they are $1,2,4,53,106,212$.

Hence these are the only options.

A more careful analysis using the chinese remainder theorem shows the group of units is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_{106}$, so the possible orders are only $1,2,4,53,106$